# Compare values from two queries and return matching values in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to get IDs of a model from two separate queries and check if the same IDs are present in both queries. If not then I must pass the string `Not present` wherever it is not or else I must pass the value.

```
class Purchase
    belongs_to :customer
    belongs_to :selected_items

class SelectedItem
    has_many :purchases
    has_many :sub_categories
    has_many :categories, through: :sub_categories

class SubCategory
    belongs_to :selected_item
    belongs_to :categories 

class Category
    has_many :sub_categories
    has_many :selected_items, through: :sub_categories

class Customer
    has_many :purchases
```

```
selected_items = @category.selected_items

def get_values(customer, selected_items)
    purchases = Purchase.where(customer_id: customer.id)
    selected_items_ids = selected_items.collect { |selected_item| selected_item.id }
    purchased_selected_items_ids = purchases.collect { |purchase| purchase.selected_item_id }
    both_present = selected_items_ids & purchased_selected_items_ids
    # after this how can I send "Not purchased" string for whichever id is not present or send the send the purchased item name wherever ids present in both?
```

In the `get_values` method I need to compare the `ids` of `SelectedItem` between `purchases` and `selected_items`. If the `id` of any item in `selected_item` is in any item in `purchases` then I should return `purchased`, if not then the `purchase` for that `selected_item` will not be in the database meaning it will return `blank` in the query. So then I must return `Not purchased` string. This is done for each customer. How can I do that? Here I am displaying the results in table in erb file. So the columns for each selected_item will be created. I should pass the values of whether each customer has purchased or not for each of the selected_item.

Comment: A customer has no relationship to selected items so this seems like a strange request.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like,

```
selected_items  = @category.selected_items

def get_values(customer, selected_items)
    purchases = Purchase.where(customer_id: customer.id)
    result = selected_items & purchases # will give common
    result.nil? ? "not_puchased" : "purchased"
end
```

Comment: Btw you can use .pluck(:id) rather than fetching full records.

Comment: Here if an item is purchased then I should send the name of each purchased item. Not "purchased".

Comment: yup... this code can be more optimized but this is one of the general solutions

Comment: @user001 now You have general Idea so, you can modify your code as per your needs

Comment: @NickM pluck to fetch purchases? I do not know. I am new to Rails. Actually I am querying the last purchase in a particular sub_category. So I did not use `pluck` or I do not yet know how to use that. I am using `group_by`. I did not put the whole query in the question.

Comment: Try going through some ActiveRecord video tutorials, you’ll be amazed what AR can do for you or rather what you can do with it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_values(customer, selected_items)
  purchases = Purchase.where(customer_id: customer.id)
  selected_items_ids = selected_items.collect { |selected_item| selected_item.id }
  purchased_selected_items_ids = purchases.collect { |purchase| purchase.selected_item_id }
  purchased = selected_items_ids & purchased_selected_items_ids
  not_purchased = (selected_items_ids - purchased_selected_items_ids) + 
                (purchased_selected_items_ids - selected_items_ids)
end
```

I think now you will be able to return both the purchased items and not purchased items. You can simply return an array [purchased, not_purchased] where both purchased and not_purchased will be array and contain respective ids or you can iterate over them and create a hash with the id as key and value will be item_name(for purchased ids)/not_purchased(for the other ids) and retuen the hash.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably better left to SQL you handle the whole situation where you want to find the purchased and not purchased items e.g.

```
  purchase_table = Purchase.arel_table
  selected_items_table = SelectedItems.arel_table
  SelectedItems.joins(:sub_categories).joins(
      purchase_table.join(selected_items_table,Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin).on(
          selected_items_table[:id].eq(purchase_table[:selected_item_id]).and(
            purchase_table[:customer_id].eq(customer.id))
      ).join_sources)
  .where(sub_categories: {category_id: @category.id}).select( 
      "selected_items.*, 
       Case 
         WHEN purchases.id IS NULL Then 'Not Purchased' 
         ELSE 'Purchased' 
       END AS purchasing_status"
   )
```

This should result in the following:

```
  SELECT 
    selected_items.*, 
    Case 
      WHEN purchases.id IS NULL Then 'Not Purchased' 
      ELSE 'Purchased' 
    END AS purchasing_status
  FROM 
    selected_items
    INNER JOIN sub_categories ON sub_categories.selected_item_id = selected_items.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN purchases ON purchases.selected_item_id = selected_items.id
       AND purchases.customer_id = [YOU CUSTOMER ID] 
  WHERE 
     sub_categories.category_id = [YOUR CATEGORY ID]
```

However this is an extremely strange schema since I would have assumed that a Customer would make selections that could ultimately be purchased and that those selections would belong to a sub_category. e.g.

```
class Customer
  has_many :selected_items
  has_many :purchases, through: :selected_items

class Purchase
  belongs_to :selected_item

class SelectedItem
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :sub_category
  has_one :purchase

class SubCategory
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :selected_items

class Category
  has_many :sub_categories
  has_many :selected_items, through: :sub_categories
```

In this schema it would be far easier to determine if a `SelectedItem` for a `Customer` was `Purchase`d or not